# Batch, comparing two files and write differences to another file

Tags: string, batch-file, grep, compare, findstr

I've searched for solution but I still have problems with it. I have two files:

```
File1.txt
 1111
 2222
 3333

File2.txt
 1111
 2222
 3333
 4444
```

and I want an output file with only differences:

```
File3.txt
 4444
```

I've tried using Findstr but it doesn't work due to too large strings. I've also tried with gerp but I can;t make it to work.

Here's my batch code (it doesn't work because of too long strings):

```
findstr /vxg:vanilla_localisation.tsv mod_localisation.tsv > raf_changes.tsv 
for /f %%a in ('^<raf_changes.tsv find /v /c ""') do echo %%a differences found
```

I've tried also with this code:

```
grep -f vanilla_localisation.tsv mod_localisation.tsv > raf_changes.tsv
```

but it creates only empty file. I'm windows user.
Hope you will help me find solution.

Cheers

Comment: If you have access to for example cygwin, you probably want `diff`, not `grep`.

Comment: I do not have access to cygwin.

Comment: Are the lines longer than 8191 characters?  How many lines are in the files, roughly?

Comment: no, they are 10-800 max
There're about 20000lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `diff` in linux

```
diff file1.txt file2.txt
3a4
>  4444
```

---

Using `grep`

```
grep -vf file1.txt file2.txt
 4444
```

---

Using `awk`

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$0]=1;next} !a[$0]' file1.txt file2.txt
 4444
```

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
findstr /v /g:file1.txt file2.txt >result.txt
```

This works for 800 char I think - it won't be quick for 20000 lines.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (file2.txt) do (
   find "%%a" <"file1.txt" || >>result.txt echo %%a
)
```

Comment: It's a bit slow, but finally works! Thank you.
Cheers

Comment: There's still something wrong with this.
My file1.txt has something like this:
"land_units_onscreen_name_Aet_Cav" "Aithiopes Hippeis" "True"

"land_units_onscreen_name_Aet_Sword" "Aithiopes Makhairaphoroi" "True"
and when I've tried to comprate it to file2.txt my cmd displays this:
File not found - land_units_onscreen_name_Aet_Cav TRUE
and my output file is just copy of file2.txt

Comment: Try the findstr solution above the find solution.  Your string has poison characters for plain batch.  The quotes affect it.

Comment: it says "Findstr search string too long"

Comment: maybe is there a way to replace those characters on different ones and place them back after whole process?
There're also tabs between " "

Comment: Try the powershell solution below from "Joachim Isaksson"

Comment: It is possible to change the quotes and change them back later, but that would require another batch file using Jscript or VBS or Powershell, and the Powershell solution alone should be more robust and works in a batch file.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am grateful :) Already found help.

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell has a diff utility if that's an option;

```
@echo off
powershell "diff (Get-Content File1.txt) (Get-Content File2.txt) | foreach {$_.InputObject}" >result.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the comm utility (http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/comm-command-examples/):

```
comm -3 file1.txt file2.txt > file3.txt
```

Comment: I'm windows user, so I can't use it